# Do I have too many partitions? I have 4 primary partitions and I'm trying to install Ubuntu alongside windows 10 (pics included)

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation

As seen in [my Disk Management window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KxAfx.png), I have 4 primary partitions. I know that C: is my windows partition, and F: is where I put all my downloads and other programs, but I do not know how important the G: and E: partitions are.

I checked the properties on the drives, and they use the Master Boot Record (MBR) system, which means I can only have 4 primary partitions.

I'm thinking of deleting the HP_RECOVERY (G:) partition, but I'm unsure of it's important to system functionality. I personally have never needed to recover my PC, but I'm not sure if I should delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could delete the partition without problems. But if you ever need to recover your windows you need a usb drive or dvd with windows install.

This will also cause you to lose all your specific HP software. And also you might need to search for your drivers yourself.

No biggy if you know what you're doing.

About dual installing: This is the tutorial that I used.

http://linuxbsdos.com/2012/05/17/how-to-dual-boot-ubuntu-12-04-and-windows-7/

It is written for Ubuntu 12.04 but the install process remains the same. Small tip ahead: give your boot partition more room than the advised 500MB.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows you should have a make recovery disks app, make and burn those disks before you get rid of the recovery partition, that is where HP puts all the files to reset your computer back to the way they sold it to you.

The program will be in a folder may be called HP tools or some such thing.

Answer (score 0):

If you can back up the largest data partition then delete it then the free space can be made into an extended partition which can then contain lots of sub partitions. You could then restore your data to a partition and install Ubuntu in another. You can do this in windows with fdisk and the Ubuntu installer should pick up the empty partitions